# How to get the passage from where the concept was found in concept insights using conceptual search?

Tags: java, ibm-watson, concept-insights

I am using concept insights for a project of mine and I was able to do label and conceptual search successfully using the GET and POST commands.

As I was done with the conceptual search, I realized that they weren't showing the passage from where the related concepts were found. I would like to do something similar to what they have done in the concept insights demo where they show a small piece of text from where the concept and the related concepts were found(They have used the TED TALKS Corpus and I am using my own corpus).

Is there any way we can do that in Java ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the Text Index Parameter of the Concept Insights output. This can be found in the explanation tag. I usually do a bit of post processing by taking 500 characters before the start of Text Index and 500 characters after the end of Text Index, trim the incomplete sentences at the beginning and end of the snippet I get, and use the result as the relevant snippet for the concept.

Comment: Yes, can you tell me how to do that since I am not familiar with it . Yes, I did see the text index part and they seem to be showing the range of the sentence.